# MoPub GDPR SDK - how to test?

Tags: mopub

Hi I am setting up the MoPub GDPR Android SDK, am getting a call to the consent dialog page on the web but get this response :

05-16 11:10:46.469 13030-13152/ E/Volley: [18308] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://ads.mopub.com/m/gdpr_consent_dialog

This means "Bad Request" and that the call is corrupt I think. Has anyone got this call to work ?

Comment: you got any solution for this?

Comment: No luck and not much help from Mopub support either unfortunately. Not sure where the best place is to go for Mopub support on the web, does anyone know ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an ideal solution, but it works.

On your test device install a VPN service app, there are lots of free ones available out there. If you're running in an emulator (or a device without Google Play) you can goto one of the many APK mirror sites to download and sideload the APK directly.
 I won't get into the obvious risks of using VPNs, or sideloading apks outside of google play, but if you're paranoid just spin up an emulator to test this.

It's important the service offers VPN servers located in countries affected by GDPR. 
Enable the VPN service on your device/emulator and make sure you're using a server located in a GDPR country (Germany, for example). Load up the app your testing, and it should now appear that you are accessing

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Pete is suggesting a VPN here. But it appears I was getting this error because I forgot to replace the AD_UNIT_ID in the `SdkConfiguration.Builder` with my Ad Unit ID.